# What happens when Name.new is called? what New method gets called?

Tags: ruby

I am just trying to figure out what happens to your code when you have .new at the bottom. What method gets implemented?

Comment: bottom means ..........?

Comment: @ArupRakshit lets say the file is called Name.rb and has all the code in it. At the bottom of the file it says name.new. what does that mean or do?

Comment: give the code.. I can't see it

Comment: This is documented in any decent Ruby book or tutorial. `new` calls the `initialize` method of that class.

Comment: @theTinMan it actually allocates memory with `allocate` first, which returns an instance of the class. Then, it calls the `initialize` method on the newly created instance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're getting at, `Name.new` at the bottom of `name.rb` will simply create a new instance of the `Name` class. The method that is called will either be the `new` class method if you have one defined in your `Name` class, or the `new` method defined in the `Class` class.

As an example:

```
class Name

  class << self
    def new
      puts "In new method in Name class"
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Calling `Name.new` using this class would result in:

```
in new method in Name class
=> #<Name:0x007fa3b2b34360>
```

As Jörg stated in the comments on this question, the `new` method may call `allocate` or `initialize` or any other methods, but it is the `new` method that is called when `Class.new` is invoked.

Comment: OP didn't give us any more information, we are helping. What if `Name` is a module, or simply a `constant` which suppse is holding a fixnum object `2`.. Then there will be an error on `Name.new`. Let OP clarify then help him. Without seeing it, answering is same as waste of effort.

Comment: I was basing my answer on what he said in his comments to you. If he changes his post, I'll change my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes OP said `name.new`.. Have you ever see a class name such as `name` or it should be `Name` ? **class** name always be a constant. anyway take it on your own risk.

Comment: Yes, agreed! I was making assumptions about what OP meant. If it helps at all though, I guess it's not a waste of effort.

Comment: No, the method that is called when you say `Name.new` is the `new` method. Period. Depending on the implementation of that method, it may or may not call other methods (such as `initialize` or `allocate`), but the method that is called is `new`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @JörgWMittag. I'll update my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `new` on a class in Ruby it'll create you a new instance of that object initialized with the arguments provided to `new`.
If you're from the Java world you might think of this as a constructor but that's not correct, it's an initializer of the values the newly created object has.

The `new` method calls the `initialize` of the class you call `new` on.
If you have not implemented this method, Ruby will look for it in its superclass.

A really contrived example:

```
class Monkey
    def initialize(name)
        puts "Hello #{name}"
    end
end

Monkey.new("Peter")
>> Hello Peter
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of your confusion may be due to the fact that you have not defined a method called `new`.

I deduce from your question that you have a class named `Name`, so let's take this for given; in Ruby, classes are first-class objects and are instances of the class `Class`; therefore, `Name` is an instance of class `Class` and you can easily see that `new` is an *instance method* of the class `Class`, that's already defined in Ruby (you could of course override it).

When you call `new` to create a new object (as in `Name.new`) the method `new` in `Class` is called; it calls `allocate` to allocate space for the new object, then it calls the `initialize` method of the object that's been allocated, passing it the arguments of the call to `new` (if any).